# Draw 'Til You Drop

Tags: code-golf, random, game

In Dungeons & Dragons 5th edition (as well as most other editions), there exists a magic item called the [*Deck of Many Things*](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/wondrous-items/#Deck_of_Many_Things). It is an incredibly powerful item, as the cards all have very strong positive or negative effects. To use the deck, a character declares a number, and then draws up to that number of cards, with the effects applying in sequence. If the character does not draw all of the cards that they declared, and it has been at least 1 hour since the last card has been drawn, the rest of the cards are automatically drawn for them and the effects applied. After each card is drawn, it is returned to the deck, and the deck is shuffled.

The following is a list of the effects of drawing each of the cards<sup>1</sup>:

- **Balance**: Your mind suffers a wrenching alteration, causing your alignment to change. Lawful becomes chaotic, good becomes evil, and vice versa. If you are true neutral or unaligned, this card has no effect on you.
- **Comet**: If you single-handedly defeat the next hostile monster or group of monsters you encounter, you gain experience points enough to gain one level. Otherwise, this card has no effect.
- **Donjon**: You disappear and become entombed in a state of suspended animation in an extradimensional sphere. Everything you were wearing and carrying stays behind in the space you occupied when you disappeared. You remain imprisoned until you are found and removed from the sphere. You can’t be located by any divination magic, but a wish spell can reveal the location of your prison. You draw no more cards.
- **Euryale**. The card’s medusa-like visage curses you. You take a -2 penalty on saving throws while cursed in this way. Only a god or the magic of The Fates card can end this curse.
- **The Fates**: Reality’s fabric unravels and spins anew, allowing you to avoid or erase one event as if it never happened. You can use the card’s magic as soon as you draw the card or at any other time before you die.
- **Flames**: A powerful devil becomes your enemy. The devil seeks your ruin and plagues your life, savoring your suffering before attempting to slay you. This enmity lasts until either you or the devil dies.
- **Fool**: You lose 10,000 XP, discard this card, and draw from the deck again, counting both draws as one of your declared draws. If losing that much XP would cause you to lose a level, you instead lose an amount that leaves you with just enough XP to keep your level.
- **Gem**: Twenty-five pieces of jewelry worth 2,000 gp each or fifty gems worth 1,000 gp each appear at your feet.
- **Idiot**: Permanently reduce your Intelligence by 1d4 + 1 (to a minimum score of 1). You can draw one additional card beyond your declared draws.
- **Jester**: You gain 10,000 XP, or you can draw two additional cards beyond your declared draws. Discard this card after drawing it.
- **Key**: A rare or rarer magic weapon with which you are proficient appears in your hands. The GM chooses the weapon.
- **Knight**: You gain the service of a 4th-level fighter who appears in a space you choose within 30 feet of you. The fighter is of the same race as you and serves you loyally until death, believing the fates have drawn him or her to you. You control this character.
- **Moon**: You are granted the ability to cast the wish spell 1d3 times.
- **Rogue**: A nonplayer character of the GM’s choice becomes hostile toward you. The identity of your new enemy isn’t known until the NPC or someone else reveals it. Nothing less than a wish spell or divine intervention can end the NPC’s hostility toward you.
- **Ruin**: All forms of wealth that you carry or own, other than magic items, are lost to you. Portable property vanishes. Businesses, buildings, and land you own are lost in a way that alters reality the least. Any documentation that proves you should own something lost to this card also disappears.
- **Skull**. You summon an avatar of death - a ghostly humanoid skeleton clad in a tattered black robe and carrying a spectral scythe. It appears in a space of the GM’s choice within 10 feet of you and attacks you, warning all others that you must win the battle alone. The avatar fights until you die or it drops to 0 hit points, whereupon it disappears. If anyone tries to help you, the helper summons its own avatar of death. A creature slain by an avatar of death can’t be restored to life.
- **Star**: Increase one of your ability scores by 2. The score can exceed 20 but can’t exceed 24.
- **Sun**: You gain 50,000 XP, and a wondrous item (which the GM determines randomly) appears in your hands.
- **Talons**: Every magic item you wear or carry disintegrates. Artifacts in your possession aren’t destroyed but do vanish.
- **Throne**: You gain proficiency in the Persuasion skill, and you double your proficiency bonus on checks made with that skill. In addition, you gain rightful ownership of a small keep somewhere in the world. However, the keep is currently in the hands of monsters, which you must clear out before you can claim the keep as yours.
- **Vizier**: At any time you choose within one year of drawing this card, you can ask a question in meditation and mentally receive a truthful answer to that question. Besides information, the answer helps you solve a puzzling problem or other dilemma. In other words, the knowledge comes with wisdom on how to apply it.
- **The Void**: This black card spells disaster. Your soul is drawn from your body and contained in an object in a place of the GM’s choice. One or more powerful beings guard the place. While your soul is trapped in this way, your body is incapacitated. A wish spell can’t restore your soul, but the spell reveals the location of the object that holds it. You draw no more cards.

(card descriptions copied from the [D&D 5th edition SRD](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd))

Some especially foolish players will draw a large number of cards at once, hoping to get at least one powerful boon to balance out the detrimental cards. As one might expect, this often results in the character's death or inability to continue to draw cards.

### The Challenge

Simulate repeated drawing from a 22-card *Deck of Many Things*, outputting each card drawn, stopping only when one of the following conditions is met:

- The character dies (via drawing **Skull**, or drawing 5 cards after drawing **Flames** or **Rogue**, without the benefit of **The Fates** or **Moon** active<sup>2</sup>).
- The character is incapable of drawing more cards (via the effects of **Donjon**, **Talons**, **The Void**<sup>3</sup>, or the character's Intelligence score dropping to 3 or lower via **Idiot**<sup>4</sup>).

### Rules

- The character's alignment, level, XP, and possessions other than the deck do not matter.
- The character's Intelligence score starts at 10.
- There is no maximum limit to the character's Intelligence or their stockpiled uses of *wish*.
- Uses of **The Fates** do not stack.
- The *wish* spell has a 1-in-3 chance of causing the character to never be able to use the *wish* spell again, in addition to its regular effect. If this occurs, the character can no longer use the spell to negate **Flames**, **Rogue**, or **Skull** - the power of **The Fates** is their only recourse.
- The character always makes the following choices:

  - **The Fates** and **Moon** are solely used to get the character out of trouble from **Skull**, **Flames**, and **Rogue**. The character will never use them to reverse the effect of **Talons** or the *wish* spell being unable to be cast again, and cannot use them to reverse the effects of **Donjon** and **The Void**. The character will immediately use one *wish* spell to negate the effects of **Skull**, **Flames**, or **Rogue** upon drawing one of them, and it will always succeed. The character will always use **The Fates** before using *wish*.
  - The character always chooses to draw more cards with the effects of **Idiot** and **Jester** (appropriately).
  - The effect of **Star** is always used to increase Intelligence by 2, to avoid having to stop drawing cards via the effect of **Idiot**.
- The NPC ally summoned by **Knight** is not powerful enough to save the character from their untimely demise.
- Any increases or decreases to Intelligence (via **Star** or **Idiot**, respectively) must be reflected in the output (either by noting the change (`+2` or `-(1d4+1)`), or by outputting the current Intelligence score after the effect takes place).
- Any changes to the number of *wish* uses the character has stockpiled must similarly be reflected in the output, including a *wish* causing the character to not be able to use *wish* anymore.
- All random selections are from uniform discrete distributions.
- You may choose any set of 22 distinct outputs to output for the cards drawn - the cards' names do not have to be used.
- You may output changes in Intelligence, *wish* uses, and *wish* becoming unusable in any consistent, unambiguous manner of your choosing.
- The character may use *wish* or the power of **The Fates** to avoid death if the appropriate card is drawn as the fifth card after drawing **Rogue** or **Flames**. Only if *wish* is unusable or all of the uses have been used, as well as **The Fates** is not drawn in time or has already been used, will the character die.
- **Fool** and **Jester** are discarded after they are drawn. All other cards are immediately returned to the deck, and the deck is then shuffled.
- If there are multiple stacks of **Rogue** and/or **Flame** active, only one use of **The Fates** or *wish* is necessary to dispel all of them.
- Drawing multiple cards at once via **Jester** or **Fool** does not advance the turn counter on **Flames** and/or **Rogue**.

### Examples

Each line represents a sequence of draws. Changes to Intelligence and *wish* uses are shown by the current value in parentheses. A `C` next to a *wish* use denotes that *wish* cannot be used anymore. A `F` denotes that the power of **The Fates** was used to avoid death. Additional comments are provided for explanatory purposes, in the form of Python-style comments.

```
Void # Can't draw with your soul ripped out of your body.
Throne, Euryale, Rogue, Star (12), Donjon # Can't draw while in suspended animation.
Moon (3), Throne, Sun, Flames (2), Fool, Idiot (6), Flames (1 C), The Fates, Skull (F), Skull # Two uses of wish were used on the two Flames draws. The second use rendered the character unable to use wish again. The Fates was used on the first Skull. When the second Skull came up, there was no way for the character to save himself, so he died.
Idiot (5), Star (7), Idiot (3) # Too dumb to draw.
Sun, Star (12), Talons # Talons destroys the deck.
Fates, Throne, Moon (2), Fates, Skull (F), Skull # Fates doesn't stack
Fates, Flames, Euryale, Fates, Skull, Void
Flames, Comet, Euryale, Gem, Knight, Key # 5 draws after Flames, the hero dies
Rogue, Balance, Throne, Gem, Idiot (8), Vizier, Sun # 5 draws plus one extra from Idiot
```

### Reference Implementation

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

deck="""Sun
Moon
Star
Throne
Key
Knight
Void
Flames
Skull
Ruin
Euryale
Rogue
Jester
Vizier
Comet
Fates
Gem
Talons
Idiot
Donjon
Balance
Fool""".split()

random.shuffle(deck)

int_stat = 10
wish_uses = 0
wish_expired = False
fates = False
turn_count = None

while True:
    card = deck.pop()
    if card == "Fates":
        if turn_count is None:
            fates = True
            print(card)
        else:
            turn_count = None
            fates = False
            print("{} (F)".format(card))
    elif card == "Moon":
        wish_uses += random.randint(1, 3)
        if turn_count is None:
            print("{} ({})".format(card, wish_uses))
        else:
            turn_count = None
            wish_uses -= 1
            print("{} ({}) ({})".format(card, wish_uses+1, wish_uses))
    elif card in ["Flames", "Rogue"]:
        if turn_count is None:
            turn_count = 5
        if fates:
            fates = False
            turn_count = None
            print("{} (F)".format(card))
        elif wish_uses > 0 and not wish_expired:
            wish_uses -= 1
            turn_count = None
            wish_now_expired = random.choice([False, False, True])
            print("{} ({}{})".format(card, wish_uses, " C" if wish_expired else ""))
            wish_expired = wish_now_expired
        else:
            print("{}".format(card))
    elif card == "Idiot":
        int_stat -= random.randint(2, 5)
        print("{} ({})".format(card, int_stat))
        if turn_count is not None:
          turn_count += 1
        if int_stat <= 3:
            break
    elif card == "Star":
        int_stat += 2
        print("{} ({})".format(card, int_stat))
    elif card == "Skull":
        if fates:
            fates = False
            turn_count = None
            print("{} (F)".format(card))
        elif wish_uses > 0 and not wish_expired:
            wish_uses -= 1
            turn_count = None
            wish_now_expired = random.choice([False, False, True])
            print("{} ({}{})".format(card, wish_uses, " C" if wish_expired else ""))
            wish_expired = wish_now_expired
        else:
            print(card)
            break
    elif card in ["Donjon", "Void", "Talons"]:
        print(card)
        break
    elif card == "Fool":
        print(card)
        if turn_count is not None:
            turn_count += 1
    elif card == "Jester":
        print(card)
        if turn_count is not None:
            turn_count += 2
    else:
        print(card)
    if card not in ["Fool", "Jester"]:
        deck.append(card)
        random.shuffle(deck)
    if turn_count is not None:
        turn_count -= 1
    if turn_count == 0:
        break
```

---

<sup>[1]: Technically, there are two variants: one with 13 cards, and one with 22 cards. We're only concerned about the full 22-card version here.</sup>

<sup>[2]: **Flame** and **Rogue** don't normally outright kill the character, but the hostile NPC is assumed to have found and killed the foolish character after they have time to draw 5 more cards. The spectre summoned by **Skull**
 is extremely difficult to fight, and it's assumed that the character doesn't win. Only divine/magical intervention via **The Fates** or **Moon** can save the foolish character from their death by these 3 cards.</sup>

<sup>[3]: We assume the character's friends are smart enough to not try to rescue the character and allow them to draw more cards.</sup>

<sup>[4]: An Intelligence score of 3 is roughly equivalent to a wild animal, which wouldn't be able to actively make the choice to draw cards.</sup>

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14145/45941)

Comment: Might be good to include some more example runs where a) the five turns expire, ideally with some bonus cards drawn in between, b) the fates is drawn twice, with and without making use of it in between.

Comment: Your reference implementation doesn't let the wish expire if it's used the moment Moon is drawn. And it also doesn't check there whether they have expired already.

Comment: One more thing: the original D&D rules mention additional cards for all of Idiot, Fool and Jester. Your rules first state that the player draws additional card for Idiot and Jester but then clarify the rule counter for Fool and Jester, and your reference implementation seems to draw only additional cards for Fool and Jester. Could you clarify/fix this?

Comment: Are we allowed to output wishes, wishes_used and intelligent even when no chances in their value occurred?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen As long as you do so unambiguously, yes.

Comment: In the first of the new examples, couldn't you still use one of the two wishes to avoid the second Skull?

Comment: @MartinEnder I think the second-to-last (`Fates, Flames, Euryale, Fates, Skull, Void`) ends because of the `Void`, not because of `Fates`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen isn't that the third-to-last? I meant the one after that and it's since been fixed.

Comment: So I'm assuming this is draw-and-put-back? Or can each card be drawn only once ? Should we reshuffle when the deck runs out? Does 'Discard' mean it gets removed from the deck ie can't be drawn again in the future?

Comment: @steenbergh I also read past it at first, but "_After each card is drawn, it is returned to the deck, and the deck is shuffled._". Only the Fool and Jester will be removed when drawn, everything else is placed in the deck again and reshuffled every time before a new card is drawn.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 379 bytes

```js
for(D=[...Array(21)].map((a,b)=>b),d={},i=10,w=e=f=t=0,F=_=>f=t=o=0,W=_=>{w--,t=0,o=w+(e?' C':''),e=1>r(2)},r=a=>0|Math.random()*a,$=1;$;){for(;d[c=r(22)];);o='',c?3>c?(t&&(t+=c),d[c]=1):4>c?f?F():0<w&&!e?W():$=0:7>c?$=0:9>c?(!t&&(t=5),f?F():0<w&&!e&&W()):10>c?(w+=1+r(2),t?(t=0,o=[w,--w]):o=w):11>c?(i-=2+r(3),o=i,$=3<i):12>c&&(i+=2,o=i):t?F():f=1,console.log(c,o),t&&(t--,$=t)}
```

#### Ungolfed

```js
let

print = (...x) => console.log(card, ...x),

// Uncomment for more human-friendly output:
// print = (...x) => console.log(`Fates Fool Jester Skull Donjon Void Talons Flames Rogue Moon Idiot Star Sun Throne Key Knight Ruin Euryale Vizier Comet Gem Balance`.split` `[card] + x.map(x => ` (${x})`).join``),

deck = [...Array(21)].map((_,i)=>i),
discard = {},

intelligence = 10,
wishUses = 0,
wishExpired = false,
fates = false,
turns = 0,
    
useFates = () => {
    fates = false
    turns = 0
    print('F')
},
useWish = () => {
    wishUses--
    turns = 0
    print(wishUses + (wishExpired ? ' C' : ''))
    wishExpired = random(2) < 1
},

random = n => Math.random() * n | 0,

canDraw = true

while(canDraw){
 // card = deck.splice(random(deck.length), 1)[0]
    while(discard[card = random(22)]);
    
    if(card){
        if(card < 3){
            // 1: Fool
            // 2: Jester
            if(turns){
                turns += card
            }
   print()
   discard[card] = 1
        }else if(card < 4){
            // 3: Skull
            if(fates){
                useFates()
            }else if(wishUses > 0 && !wishExpired){
                useWish()
            }else{
                print()
                canDraw = false
            }
        }else if(card < 7){
            // 4: Donjon
            // 5: Void
            // 6: Talons
            print()
            canDraw = false
        }else if(card < 9){
            // 7: Flames
            // 8: Rogue
            if(!turns){
                turns = 5
            }
            if(fates){
                useFates()
            }else if(wishUses > 0 && !wishExpired){
                useWish()
            }else{
                print()
            }
        }else if(card < 10){
            // 9: Moon
            wishUses += 1 + random(2)
            if(!turns){
                print(wishUses)
            }else{
                turns = 0
                wishUses--
                print(wishUses + 1, wishUses)
            }
        }else if(card < 11){
            // 10: Idiot
            intelligence -= 2 + random(3)
            print(intelligence)
            if(intelligence <= 3){
                canDraw = false
            }
        }else if(card < 12){
            // 11: Star
            intelligence += 2
            print(intelligence)
        }else{
            print()
        }
    }else{
        // 0: Fates
        if(!turns){
            fates = true
            print()
        }else{
            useFates()
        }
    }
    
    if(turns){
        turns--
        if(!turns){
            canDraw = false
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation of Output

Cards range from 0-21 as follows:

- 0: Fates
- 1: Fool
- 2: Jester
- 3: Skull
- 4: Donjon
- 5: Void
- 6: Talons
- 7: Flames
- 8: Rogue
- 9: Moon
- 10: Idiot
- 11: Star
- 12 though 21: Sun, Throne, Key, Knight, Ruin, Euryale, Vizier, Comet, Gem, Balance

A reversal of Skull, Flames, or Rogue via The Fates is denoted with a `0`.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 792 bytes

Previous version using card names, before I found out that any 22 distinct outputs are allowed.

```js
d=`Sun Moon Star Throne Key Knight Void Flames Skull Ruin Euryale Rogue Jester Vizier Comet Fates Gem Talons Idiot Donjon Balance Fool`.split` `,i=10,w=0,W=!1,f=!1,t=null,F=()=>{f=!1,t=null,_('F')},U=()=>{w--,t=null,_(w+(W?' C':'')),W=1>r(2)},_=(...a)=>console.log(c+a.map(b=>` (${b})`).join``),r=a=>0|Math.random()*a,$=!0;for(;$;)c=d.splice(r(d.length),1)[0],'Fates'==c?null==t?(f=!0,_()):F():'Moon'==c?(w+=1+r(2),null==t?_(w):(t=null,w--,_(w+1,w))):'Idiot'==c?(i-=2+r(3),_(i),3>=i&&($=!1)):'Star'==c?(i+=2,_(i)):'Flames'==c||'Rogue'==c?(null==t&&(t=5),f?F():0<w&&!W?U():_()):'Skull'==c?f?F():0<w&&!W?U():(_(),$=!1):'Donjon'==c||'Void'==c||'Talons'==c?(_(),$=!1):'Fool'==c?null!==t&&(t+=1):'Jester'==c?null!==t&&(t+=2):_(),['Fool','Jester'].includes(c)||d.push(c),null!==t&&t--,0===t&&($=!1)
```

#### Ungolfed

```js
let

deck = `Sun Moon Star Throne Key Knight Void Flames Skull Ruin Euryale Rogue Jester Vizier Comet Fates Gem Talons Idiot Donjon Balance Fool`.split` `,

intelligence = 10,
wishUses = 0,
wishExpired = false,
fates = false,
turns = null,
    
useFates = () => {
    fates = false
    turns = null
    print('F')
},
useWish = () => {
    wishUses--
    turns = null
    print(wishUses + (wishExpired ? ' C' : ''))
    wishExpired = random(2) < 1
},

print = (...x) => console.log(card + x.map(x => ` (${x})`).join``),
random = n => Math.random() * n | 0,

canDraw = true

while(canDraw){
    card = deck.splice(random(deck.length), 1)[0]
    
    switch(card){
    case 'Fates':
        if(turns === null){
            fates = true
            print()
        }else{
            useFates()
        }
        break
    case 'Moon':
        wishUses += 1 + random(2)
        if(turns === null){
            print(wishUses)
        }else{
            turns = null
            wishUses--
            print(wishUses + 1, wishUses)
        }
        break
    case 'Idiot':
        intelligence -= 2 + random(3)
        print(intelligence)
        if(intelligence <= 3){
            canDraw = false
        }
        break
    case 'Star':
        intelligence += 2
        print(intelligence)
        break
   case 'Flames':
   case 'Rogue':
        // Changed Condition
        if(turns === null){
            turns = 5
        }
        
        if(fates){
            useFates()
        }else if(wishUses > 0 && !wishExpired){
            useWish()
        }else{
            // Added
            print()
        }
        break
    case 'Skull':
        if(fates){
            useFates()
        }else if(wishUses > 0 && !wishExpired){
            useWish()
        }else{
            print()
            canDraw = false
        }
        break
    case 'Donjon':
    case 'Void':
    case 'Talons':
        print()
        canDraw = false
        break
    case 'Fool':
        if(turns !== null){
            turns += 1
        }
        break
    case 'Jester':
        if(turns !== null){
            turns += 2
        }
        break
    default:
        print()
    }
    
    if(!['Fool', 'Jester'].includes(card)){
        deck.push(card)
    }
    
    if(turns !== null){
        turns--
    }
    
    if(turns === 0){
        canDraw = false
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mego honestly, I didn't really get it as well as I should've until seeing this answer, was well done; easy to understand when seeing the full names. If you change it can you keep a version with the full names?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Certainly, I'll be sure to preserve the current full-name version in the future.

Comment: @Mego it was directed at OP, and was just saying "the version with the actual card names spelled fully made this implementation easy to read. If you shave bytes off, keep this one too, labeled as 'ungolfed'".

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Updated.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>481</s> <s>480</s> <s>476</s> <s>470</s> <s>453</s> <s>439</s> <s>437</s> 436 bytes

```java
v->{var r="";Math M=null;int i=10,d=22,c,F=0,t=0,w=0,W=0,j=2;for(j*=M.random();;){c=d;c*=M.random();r+=" "+c;t=c<1?(r+=t<(F=1)?"":"F"+(F=0))==""?-1:-1:c<2?0*(w+=M.random()*3-(t>0?0:1)):c<4?F>0?-1:t<1?6:t:c<5?F*w*W>(F=0)?-1:1:c>19?t+(t>0*d--*j++?j%2+1:0):t;W=c>1&c<5&w*W>0?(int)(M.random()*3)%2+0*w--:W;i-=c==5?M.random()*3+2:c==6?-2:0;r+=c>1&c<5&F>0?"F"+(F=0):c>0&c<5?"w"+w+"W"+W:c>4&c<7?"i"+i:"";if(--t==0|c==5&i<4|c>6&c<10)return r;}}
```

Ported the Python3 reference implementation in Java, and then golfed it down.

-46 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Card outputs:**

> `0`: Fates
> `1`: Moon
> `2`: Flames
> `3`: Rogue
> `4`: Skull
> `5`: Idiot
> `6`: Star
> `7`/`8`/`9`: Donjon/Void/Talons
> `20`/`21`: Fool/Jester
>
> `10-19`: everything else (Sun/Throne/Key/Knight/Ruin/Euryale/Vizier/Comet/Gem/Balance)

Output format for wishes left, wishes used, intelligence left, and flag used:

```java
4w1W0
4       // Card drawn
 w1     // New amount of wishes left
   W0   // Whether the wishes used flag is active (1) or inactive (0)

5i6
5       // Card drawn
 i6     // New intelligence

0F0
0       // Card drawn
 F0     // Fates used
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##VVJRa9swEH7XrxCCFcuKYtlN0lWKopcR6CAdbGN5GHvQZCeV69jFkRNKm9@endpudGDZ3Hd33538fbU9WF6X9@csRULipQ3VHuUSr7quRQUAjd0Bcinx1247VBJNJP52PzQNmkp8U/ouoBkgwfboKvuYXUv8qWvrrs1@dL7Mvtuma4FP8Bwy1aHqH8Odb7e4avYVKuLArmtQAQM/V/tQ9SjNEHKN3e/xyvr2CWHsW8A31lX4NoYYhvWRwiVxBD5QBegJwWsfbPAO3@IW6/OBL54Otse9JkStbLjDK93C3gr4sNe5GJW6KEZutNRiFOAc4azh1LpQm65P6lSvxr1ty26XUKXok9Olcv@BPdMEE@ZU0G6emwTiME@WOqeGEEmWhEEgKNWwg@G5hMfNCyPS5Mje8aSXPAkLYYTMKYWKiVlCBMUBSGcyADQ1y/SYrhcvfDEFTIv82gQWO9OS87RmzNQfCpZLQWVQaw0FF9B5EfuESeDeNHk/lEKxSI@cy7XyXDutp@Z9nhUSsJnhhRTxqn/54nL/7gZriIgaciTsyMiasDVgE8CuDPGEeQn/328SzoPW4jlOufDzybNbzKAmF7SvwtC3uFen01lFGR@G3w3I@KbmIYq8Ay8kr7r//GXpqw@yDH8ZwsMQcDHFr2vjbXSrfElHDd@0VtjPdTGFD2P0JQkuegS/7cbdEMYPwBuaNmnHLokWoW@WOp3/AA) or [**Try it here with pretty-printed output**](https://tio.run/##fZVdb9MwFIbv9yssa0x23ZQkawtL6kZ8BQEqIIboBePCJF7nkjqV4zQa2377OE4G2yRSqWnk48fv@UyyFjvhrfNft1khqgothNJXBwgpbaU5F5lEH90SoVNrlF6hjHwrVY52NAbrzQH8VVZYlaGPSCOObnfe/GonDDIc43gh7AVacF0XRQyCSPHAH@Y8DIfZMOX@0MLVwLWEa83D@Lw0ZD3gi5EROi83hMYxvcp4HmePjIZxjDDLYsuzWZAQWNsZSXlAE4wjnGIGC59SDjEkXhDBL5uFiT8gDXugMzj2iJ37iR8FlAIxTlJYAWxBdBpZME2SdNAMlvNWz22B0jw4SSxzJwe55w3WjCXrJyELIp9GNl5yAI7g5JE75ycE8qbkoVMKsD9oPC9axsrjGeeT5OE@CyOwTRMvjHyX6l89F9y/3CAM31kT3GDWMLzEbAm2MdieJVhhpiKovzonnmc596@dlyM1G19n8ykwgU@NtLXRyMQ3N7ex6@O2/llAH@/auXNd3sAwkK7x338gQbtJePoUfarttrYonKAubrQSG1lF7bZr4l2zY6RmPJzAjTHaboIbcGwvP4OmJfdDtDVqJ6x85P0R@WgIDUyaHmXEDVargVqTGRm5LWBmXxQFwcgnKTQNDxFGKWhXh0GM/0cDGjQttihL3eB@xZA01yntFAuX8WGwhz6@p7@Uq1ruhcf38OkvSKsHBnKiWupdrkqr@qBpB51aYXqZZy3yutTrUvdW5nkLuWe@Fzlpka@iKHXVX2G/C6judxUEndCFKbXsp8KW@iAv@5HjDtFqdWH7qXHXmlrtCWnSMm9qcymKPTFNuyqp30qafqor@KtyI/dE1RX8rdz0I13BX4pC6Kw/qLCreFqWRT/Tlfy9rGxf4O14NuTsLGd02d3cGdKo6kJWqJDnNkLwaKE7Q13JHAwh3SOnHui4D01RqJWEXP6p7TsMZxtG0za7w4C0j3brlf49c3oJ6WxGZW1HW/f2KDR8IvCZxnfvm5vbPw).

```java
v->{                        // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  var r="";                 //  Result-String, starting empty
  Math M=null;              //  Static Math to save bytes
  int i=10,                 //  Intelligence, starting at 10
      d=22,                 //  Amount of cards in the deck, starting at 22
      c,                    //  Current card drawn
      F=0,                  //  Fates flag, starting at inactive
      t=0,                  //  Turn-counter, starting at 0
      w=0,                  //  Wishes left, starting at 0
      W=0,                  //  Wishes used flag, starting at 0
      j=2;for(j*=M.random() //  Whether Jester/Fool is drawn first of the two, random 0/1
      ;;){                  //  Loop indefinitely:
    c=d;c*=M.random();      //   Draw a random 0-21 card (or less if Fool/Jester is gone)
    r+=" "+c;               //   Append the result with a space and this card
    t=c<1?                  //   If the card was Fates:
      (r+=t<(F=1)           //    Set the Fates-flag to active
                 ?          //    And if the turn-counter is 0:
        ""                  //     Append nothing
      :                     //    Else (the turn-counter is larger than 0):
       "F"+(F=0))           //     Append that Fates was used (and make Fates inactive)
      ==""?-1:-1            //    Then set the turn-counter to -1 (none)
    :c<2?                   //   If the card was Moon instead:
      0*(w+=M.random()*3    //    Increase the wishes by 0-2 randomly
         -(t>0?             //    Then, if the turn-counter is larger than 0
            0               //     Leave the (0-based random) wishes the same
           :                //    Else:
            1))             //     Subtract 1 from the (0-based random) wishes
      -1                    //    Set the turn-counter to -1 (none)
    :c<4?                   //   If the card was Flames or Rogue instead:
      F>0?                  //    If the Fates-flag is active:
       -1                   //     Set the turn-counter to -1 (none)
      :t<1?                 //    Else-if the turn-counter is 0 or -1 (none):
       6                    //     Set the turn-counter to 6
      :                     //    Else:
       t                    //     Leave the turn-counter the same
    :c<5?                   //   If the card was Skull instead:
        F                   //    If the Fates-flag is inactive
        *w                  //    or the amount of wishes is smaller than 1
        *W<1                //    or the wishes used flag is inactive
            +0*(F=0)?       //    (And set the Fates-flag to inactive)
         1                  //     Set the turn-counter to 1
        :                   //    Else:
         -1                 //     Set the turn-counter to -1 (none)
    :c>19?                  //   If the card was Fool or Jester instead:
      t+(t>0*d--            //    Remove the Fool/Jester from the Deck
            *j++            //    And increase `j` (Fool/Jester) by 1
                ?           //    If the turn-counter was not 0 or -1 (none):
          j%2+1             //     Increase either by 1 (Fool) or 2 (Jester)
         :                  //    Else:
          0)                //     Leave the turn-counter the same by increasing with 0
    :                       //   Else:
     t;                     //    Leave the turn-counter unchanged
    W=c>1&c<5               //   If the card drawn was Flames, Rogue or Skull,
      &w                    //   and the amount of wishes is at least 1,
        *W>0?               //   and the wishes used flag is active
       (int)(M.random()*3)%2//    Randomly set the wishes used flag to one of (0,0,1)
       +0*w--               //    And decrease the wishes left by 1
      :                     //   Else:
       W;                   //    Keep the wishes used flag the same
    i-=c==5?                //   If the card drawn was Idiot:
        M.random()*3+2      //    Decrease the intelligence by 2-5 randomly
       :c==6?               //   Else-if the card drawn was Star:
        -2                  //    Increase the intelligence by 2
       :                    //   Else:
        0;                  //    Leave the intelligence the same
    r+=c>1&c<5              //   If the card drawn was Flames, Rogue or Skull,
       &F>0?                //   and Fates is active
        "F"+(F=0)           //    Append that Fates was used (and make Fates inactive)
       :c>0&c<5?            //   Else-if the card drawn was Moon, Flames, Rogue or Skull:
        "w"+w+"W"+W         //    Append the amount of wishes left and wishes used flag
       :c>4&c<7?            //   Else-if the card drawn was Idiot or Star:
        "i"+i               //    Append the amount of intelligence left
       :                    //   Else:
        "";                 //    Append nothing
    if(--t                  //   Decrease the turn-counter by 1
          ==0               //   And if the turn-counter is now 0,
       |c==5                //   or the card drawn was Idiot,
             &i<4           //   and the intelligence dropped below 4,
       |c>6&c<10)           //   or the card drawn was Donjon, Void or Talons:
         return r;}}        //    Return the result of the game
```

Comment: `Jester; Fates; Ruin; Euryale; Gem; Ruin; Ruin; Rogue(Fates used) Gem; Balance; Throne; Rogue(wishes left: 0; wishes used: 0); Rogue(wishes left: 0; wishes used: 0);` Why did it stop?

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks! Should be fixed now. If you spot any other mistakes, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 1173 bytes

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){val d="Sun Moon Star Throne Key Knight Void Flames Skull Ruin Euryale Rogue Jester Vizier Comet Fates Gem Talons Idiot Donjon Balance Fool".split(" ");var c=(Math.random()*22).toInt();var i=10;var u=0;var e=false;var f=false;var t=1;r@while(true){when(c){15->{if(t>=1){f=true;println(c)}else{t = 1;f = false;println("${d[c]} (F)")}}1->{u+=(Math.random()*3).toInt()+1;if(t>=1){println("${d[c]} ($u)")}else{t=1;u-=1;println("${d[c]} (${u + 1}) ($u)")}}in arrayOf(7,11)->{if(t>=1){t=5};if(f){f=false;t=1;println("${d[c]} (F)")}else if(u>0&&!e){u-=1;t=1;val n=(Math.random()*3).toInt();println("${d[c]} ($u$e)");e=n==0}else{println(d[c])}}18->{i-=(Math.random()*4).toInt()+2;println("${d[c]} ($i)");if (t!=0){t+=1};if(i<=3){break@r}}2->{i+=2;println("${d[c]} ($i)")}8->{if(f){f=false;t=1;println("${d[c]} (F)")}else if(u>0&&!e){u-=1;t=1;val n=(Math.random()*3).toInt();println("${d[c]} ($u$e)");e=n==0}else{println(c);break@r}}in arrayOf(6,17,19)->{println(d[c]);break@r}21->{println(d[c]);if(t!=0){t += 1}}12->{println(d[c]);if(t!=0){t+=2}}else->{println(d[c])}};if((c !in arrayOf(12,21))){c=(Math.random()*23).toInt()};if(t!=0){t-=1}else{break}}}
```

It's runnable, too. - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVPRbtMwFP2V26iabNJWdcZgkLkaMIrGNCGt014QDyZ1WjPXnhx7U4n87cVO1K60Hc@82Jbu8bnnnGvfayuFWq1Kp2DBhELMzKr3H4xhy7OJNULNRrh@ZBKmNJkEzLXWCiaWGbidG604XPElXCkxm1u402IKY8kWvILJvZMSbpxQ8NmZJZMcbvTMcfjKK8sN3InfImyf9IJbGDMbrnzhC7hlUqsKLqdCW7jQ6lfo9pFJpgoOY61lMqgepLAogQTnj0FFQdE1s/OBYWqqFwi/yjI8sPpSWdQCBCXD5uBou3NaMlnx5lxunS0luTl/mgvJkTWO4/ppzhUqcE1O@qNalMiOKMF1SWM1fwjZWBnrngeK2gIFkpdhbSnX9aRbT78XPzygMU6w9yRwuXRX9fFGdEryTat9jq6LJG3DoNf1w3IAVTtIgXi8vuDDGFic6bcSve0RgrcNWXriY88yemvF24O043VvCGg3Gh4ddUJKjYZ4Ib4S9bKxQzpdlwfOnFNF6bC1tUZFSIzrNErt79K@fs4rO0QsIq0oAdkOHQaLKSWNR3FGj3H903B2f268zyJ5Sl@k8KdtUP9XNAXONw62BvumR8Js38XZ/hXiBpyRvVJ8BG1CkIb3G/LO/oEJSflGyi7GN@GiAjpbekjWywjGuN7/o8/W/RZ9SKs12gj23q9WfwA)

There's probably lots of bugs... let me know in the comments!

Comment: Infinite loop printing `Fool` or `Jester`.